# Disable Border of cell in iOS 16 / Xcode 14

Tags: swift, ios16

iOS 16/Xcode 14 adds a blue border around cells in sidebar. How can this be removed?

My cell is a custom class derived from UICollectionViewListCell.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

allowsFocus is a new property in iOS 15. Its use is covered in this WWDC video: [Build Desktop-class iPad app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10070/) (see minute ~15:25). Perhaps the default (or the implementation) changed in iOS 16. In any case, setting it to false removes the border.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
  collectionView.allowsFocus = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Phantom59's answer. You can still use `allowsFocus` without the focus border by setting the UICollectionViewCell's `focusEffect` to nil:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    cell.focusEffect = nil
}
```

More info: [Focus-based navigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/focus-based_navigation)